# Finding distance to an LED

Tags: image-processing, camera, led

Imagine you have Christmas-tree style LED light at a distance D from a camera.

Knowing the properties of both the LED light (such as shape and intensity) and the camera (such as focal length), is it possible to calculate the distance from the camera to the LED light using a snapshot?

If yes, how accurate would the measurement be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bright light sources itself are not good for this** as the bright light usually distorts the neighboring space with **MIE+Rayleight** scattering creating haze dependent on many things not just illumination. Also there are few problems in the camera itself like the bright H or V lines caused by charge jump across scan-line and or lens flares (that star like or polygonial shape usually rotated and sometimes rainbow colored) **making really hard to measure the size in the image** in some cases.

[image: problems]

In case your  image contains such problems I would use some other objects of known size like Christmas balls (or the light holders/sockets if visible/usable) also what about tree leafs for evergreen they usually all the same size. The precision can be estimated like this:

If **FOV** of camera in `x` direction is `60deg` and resolution is `640x480` (assuming square pixels) then one pixel is `da = 60deg/640pix=0.09375deg` angle accuracy. So for `h=5cm=0.05m` big object `d=2.5m` distant from camera I see it like this:

[image: sketch]

```
tan(ang) = h/d
--------------
ang = atan( h/d) = atan(0.05/2.5) = 1.14 deg
p = ang / da = 1.14/0.09375 = 12.2214 pixel
```

so image can be either 12 or 13 pixel big so computing the distance back

```
d = h/tan(p*da)
--------------
d0 = 0.05/tan(12*0.09375) = 2.54615m
d1 = 0.05/tan(13*0.09375) = 2.35024m

acc = 100*max(d-d0,d-d1)/d = 100*max(0.04615,0.25024)/2.5 = ~ 10.0096%
```

Now as you can see the precision is affected by object size and distance from camera. Also on the **FOV** and resolution of camera itself.

To improve this you can use sub-pixel precision object measurement ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem, in my case, is that I want it to work in complete darkness. I need the object to be self-illuminating. Would it be easier if the object glowed uniformly (like radium)?

Comment: @user2977125 if your image will not contained mentioned errors then you should be fine (you need to carefully set exposure time and or shutter) .... another option would be to use 2 cameras (or 1 taking image from 2 known positions). Hard to recommend anything without seeing actual image you are dealing with ....