# adding lens flare in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to create a lens flare in OpenGL C++. I referred this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqX09lt5-F0) and [star rendering](https://www.seedofandromeda.com/blogs/51-procedural-star-rendering) code.

```
double calculateGlowSize(double diameter, double temperature, double distance) {
    static const double DSUN = 1392684.0;
    static const double TSUN = 5778.0;

    // Georg's magic formula
    double d = distance; // Distance
    double D = diameter * DSUN;
    double L = (D * D) * pow(temperature / TSUN, 4.0); // Luminosity
    return 0.016 * pow(L, 0.25) / pow(d, 0.5); // Size
}
```

but i want the output to be more like the image shown below.

[image]

How do i create a lens flare effect?

Comment: See [Finding distance to an LED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764104/2521214) to distinguish what kind of effect you want. In your image I see scattering (that glow) , light trap or charge jump (the horizontal brightest line) and iris flare (those thinner bright lines emitting from center of light source). I do not see any lens flare (like in your video) So which one you really want or all of them ? Some games fake those with alpha blending and animated texture. The flares are usually dependent on the angle between center screen ray and Light source which is converted to displacement.

Comment: In the links here: [Is it possible to make realistic n-body solar system simulation in matter of size and mass?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214) you can find some stuff needed for your app (like BV to RGB etc)

Comment: from quick search this looks promising [Pseudo Lens Flare](http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.sk/2013/02/pseudo-lens-flare.html)